# Netbeans 15 - how to recognise external stylesheet css in code hints?

Tags: php, html, css, code-hinting, netbeans-15

I am new to Netbeans version 15. 
I've been using Dreamweaver for 20+ years.
I use external stylesheets like this
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">`
Dreamweaver is very nice and shows code hints from these external stylesheets. 
How do I get Netbeans to do that as well? 
Netbeans shows "class not found" and suggests I create it.